# How to add Custom option value on coupon rules Magneto 2

Tags: php, magento2

How to add Custom option value on coupon rules Magneto 2. I have a product which have some custom option like size, color etc. with different value, I want give discount on basic of size = 7'. I don't want use sku custom option.. Let me know how I fix it.
https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-custom-total
Moulde I use for Discount but i have face a problem.
one Data I can't get cart information

```
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Set the state (not sure if this is neccessary)
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Getting the object managers dependencies 
$quote = $obj->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$helper = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');

// Get quote and cart items collection
$quote = $helper->getQuote();
$quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems();

$coupon_code = 'Test23';
// Get cart contents
$cart= $helper->getCart();  
foreach ($quoteitems as $item)
{

}
```

It goes to the infinity loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one Run fast that's why here we can't load quote total, For Discount given you must set session core cookies which allow giving discount...